# Problem with linker script (undefined reference to `puts')

Tags: assembly, gcc, linker, linker-errors, ld

So, here is my problem.

I have been trying to link an .asm with a .c file using a ld script, but all I get is
*hello.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `puts'*

My files are as follows:

bootinit.asm:

```
    global main
    extern zain

    KERNEL_STACK_SIZE equ 4096                  ; size of stack in bytes

        section .bss
        align 4                                     ; align at 4 bytes
        kernel_stack:                               ; label points to beginning of memory
            resb KERNEL_STACK_SIZE                  ; reserve stack for the kernel
            mov esp, kernel_stack + KERNEL_STACK_SIZE   ; point esp to the start of the
                                                    ; stack (end of memory area)

            
    section .text
    main:
        mov ecx,'A'
        mov edx, 1
        int 0x80
        call zain 
        ret
```

hello.c:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void zain(){
            printf("Hello! \n\n");

            
    }
```

linker.ld:

```
    ENTRY(main)

    MEMORY {
        bootsector(rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x70000, LENGTH = 50k 
    }
```

makefile:

```
    ARCH_PREFIX:=i386
    LINKER=linker.ld

    LDFLAGS = \
        -T$(LINKER)

    C_FILES := $(shell find ./ -type f -name '*.c' | sort)
    ASM_FILES := $(shell find ./ -type f -name '*.asm' | sort)
    OBJ := $(ASM_FILES:.asm=.o) $(C_FILES:.c=.o)


    all:  bootFinal.bin 

    bootFinal.bin: bootinit.elf
        objcopy --binary-architecture=i386:x86-64  --remove-section=.comment $< $@

    bootinit.elf: $(OBJ)
        ld  -melf_x86_64 -T$(LINKER) $(OBJ)  -o $@ 

    %.o: %.asm
        nasm $< -f elf64  -o $@

    %.o: %.c
        gcc -I/usr/include  -m64 -libc  -Wall -Wextra -Werror  -c -o $@ $<
```

The .c and the .asm can be linked without problem and call one another if I run

`gcc -m64 $(OBJ) -o $@`

instead of the corresponding ld command, but this doesn't take into account the linker.ld .

I tried the -lc option but it doesn't work either.

I use fedora 33 if that plays any role.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `-libc` is wrong (correct would be `-lc` at the end of the command, but that is implicitly appended by the compiler anyway) and above that ineffective when used with `-c`.  You need to add all relevant libraries during the link, not during compilation.

Comment: Also, the whole `kernel_stack` thing doesn't make any sense.  The OS provides a stack for you, there's no need to make your own.  And the code you try to use for this purpose won't work (you can't put code into `.bss` and even if you could, you would have to jump there to execute it which you don't).

Comment: Really though, I don't get what all the effort is for.  You don't need a linker script.  You don't need to allocate a stack.  You don't need to invoke the linker manually.  Just let the C compiler deal with all of this.  Assemble each file into an object, then use the C compiler to link them all into a binary.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Using both -libc along with -c is the result of me ending up trying almost random solutions based on what I've read here so far

Comment: Well the solution for the problem you mentioned is to provide `-lc` to the linker instead of the compiler.  You must place `-lc` at the end of the command line for this.  However, I am not sure if this is going to lead to a useful program.  What are you trying to achieve and why do you make this so complicated?

Comment: As I previously wrote, I tried the -lc option but it didn't work. For the time being I've resorted to using -I/usr/lib/libc.so -which must be doing pretty much the same. Yet I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" whenever I run the .bin. I think that I'll have to read some material before I proceed to work with low-level programming, and I would appreciate any suggestions, just like any possible solution to my new error. The strace command does not show anything of much use

Comment: Regarding your question, I am planning to contribute to some low-level programming projects, but I may be too ignorant to do so anytime soon

Comment: I don't understand why you even have that `objconv` step in there.  Linux runs ELF files.  Converting them to some other format only means that the resulting binary won't run.  Your whole code looks like you mixed up tutorials for embedded, kernel, and hosted development into some sort of unholy abomination.  I don't understand the purpose of all of this and your comments do not enlighten me either.  The only thing that is certain is that there is so much strange stuff going on with your project, I can't even tell what specifically is wrong with it.

Comment: The initial purpose was to call a c function from the asm file. The c function would just print "Hello". A linker would set an origin for the asm file. The  .bss section and the kernel_stack were copy/paste from a tutorial, and it is definitely wrong that I didn't remove it afterwards.

Comment: Would an answer help you that just shows how to do the thing you want to do instead of trying to fix your scripts?

Comment: Note that if you get a segfault, it might be related to stack misalignment.  Not sure about that though.

Comment: Yes, that would be great!

Comment: `mov esp, kernel_stack + KERNEL_STACK_SIZE` is *in* the BSS, where nothing will run it.  (And you can't have non-zero bytes in the BSS anyway; NASM will warn you about this).  Why do you call it a *KERNEL* stack, anyway?  You're linking this into a user-space program to run under Linux, right?  That's why you're using C library functions like printf / puts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate an assembly file into a normal C program, you just write your assembly code and link it in the program as normal.  For example, you can simply do

### main.asm

```
        global  main:function
        extern  zain
        section .text
main:   push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        call    zain
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

### hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void zain(){
        printf("Hello! \n\n"); 
}
```

and then assemble, compile, and link like this:

```
nasm -felf64 main.asm
cc -o hello main.o hello.c
```

This'll do the right thing and you end up with a working binary.  There's no need to write linker scripts, initialisation code, stack set up code, or to even invoke the linker yourself.  Just let the C compiler deal with all this.

One caveat is that you need to fulfil the AMD64 SysV ABI whenever you call C functions.  This not only mandates which arguments go into which registers, but also tells you that the stack pointer must be aligned to a multiple of 16 on function call.  For this reason, a `push rbp; mov rbp, rsp` prologue is used.  It pushes 8 bytes on the stack to restore the alignment that was lost when the startup code pushed the return address of `main`.